# AppFabric Caching - works locally but not from another machine

Tags: caching, appfabric, azure-caching

I've have added my domain account permissions to Windows AppFabric 1.1 Caching using the "grant" Powershell command. A sample app runs locally on the machine itself fine. Also, I'm able to telnet to the port 22233 from another box successfully (I'm pretty sure its not firewall issue).

Could this be IIS permissions somehow? I don't see a site created under IIS. Is there a log I can check to see specifically why the remote calls are getting rejected with a "ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later."

Answer (score 0):

You granted permissions your account to AppFaric Cache, but are you sure that your app runs under this account ? If this is a WebSite, this another user (ApplicationPoolIdentity).

Try to grant your machine (by adding a $ at the end) or run your app under your granted user.

To be sure it is a problem in security, you can try to disable it at server side, just for testing purpose.

```
Set-CacheClusterSecurity -SecurityMode None -ProtectionLevel None
```

please find msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921012%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).

Comment: weird thing. I turned the security off and now it doesn't work on the server or client.

Comment: client and server securiy settings have to be the same. Disable security in the client

Comment: That got the test app working on the server again, but same error on the client again.

Comment: Are calls to AppFabric normally revealed in Fiddler? Actually just tested that and nothing in fiddler on client or server.

Comment: you can not see them in fiddler. so you can use the use on the server but not from your client ?

Comment: Yes, works on the server and does not work remotely. I have used telnet to connect to port 22233 and it seems to connect.

Comment: could you add error codes in your question ? (such aa ERRCA0017). also check that cache host name is valid and reachable from your client

Comment: I know I've run into issues with AppFabric and it's need to use NetTcp as its communication protocol.  When having errors I would always check that the NetTcp service was running on the machine.